# Produce a sequence count by factor in R

Tags: r

I have simple dataset, one row with factors - I'd like to create a second column (`SEQ`) and count/sequence the factor `LO` column

```
LO  SEQ
a   1
a   2
a   3
b   1
b   2
```

I want to count the `LO` factors like so...i.e. I want to create the `SEQ` column.
Looks so easy - but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `getanID`

```
library(splitstackshape)
getanID(df1, 'LO')[]
#    LO .id
#1:  a   1
#2:  a   2
#3:  a   3
#4:  b   1
#5:  b   2
```

Comment: Interesting function.

Comment: Yeah - I marked this as duplicate already, but this is really elegant..!